# SE Linux Android 9 AOSP: Adding a permission in platform_app.te file leading to a build failure

Tags: build, android-source, android-9.0-pie, selinux

I am working on Android9 AOSP, when I add a permission in my platform_app.te (located in /system/sepolicy/public/platform_app.te), my build fails.
`system/sepolicy/public/platform_app.te:10:"ERROR 'unknown type xyz_service' at token ';' on line "`

The permission that am adding is `allow platform_app xyz_service:binder { call transfer };`

Background on xyz_service:-
It is a service started by init and its '.te' file is located in /system/sepolicy/vendor/xyz_service.te

One reason I could think of is that the xyz_service.te resides in /system/sepolicy/**vendor** while the other file is in /system/sepolicy/**public**. Moving it to /**public** from /**vendor** gives more issues. And of-course you cannot have the files in both locations as it results in 'Duplicate declaration of type' error. Can anyone please guide me, thanks!

Comment: Vendor sepolicies rules are usually located in `device/<manufacturer>/<device>/sepolicy` and integrated by setting `BOARD_VENDOR_SEPOLICY_DIRS` in the corresponding `BoardConfig.mk`. But if you want to keep it in `/system/sepolicy` I guess you should look at the issues you get when you move `xyz_service.te` to `/public`.

Answer (score 1):

xyz_service type is defined in /system/sepolicy/vendor/xyz_service.te and you are trying to access it from  system/sepolicy/public/platform_app.te where it's not accessible. please check file.te available in system/sepolicy/public and defined xyz_service type in this file.te to get access in system/sepolicy/public/platform_app.te.